# How to install wso2 application server as a Windows service

Tags: wso2, wso2-as

In the 4.x version of the application server, it was possible to install the application server as a service via install.bat.  Is there similar functionality in 5.0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature has been removed from WSO2 products after Carbon 4.0.0 (which AS 5.0.0 is based on) This [post](http://engwar.com/post/678) may be helpful for you if you need to configure it using 3rd party projects.